# DateTime stored as US in web app...need to change to UK?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, web-applications, cloud, orchardcms

A table in my db 'DeliveryRunsHistory' has a column 'date', the user can select a date from the screen and search this table for any records which have the selected date, then display the results.

This works fine from my local machine but when I deploy the web application to the cloud and access it through the URL it doesnt. Result keep coming back as empty. Exactly the same code & DB as its just a copy.

Using Orchard 1.6 for this project I used Ilogger to record the process. After looking through the logs it seems if the date is below 12th of the month it will work. Any over and it wont. So im guessing this is because the time format is set to US, when I need it to be UK.

From the control panel on the cloud I have set it to UK and the date is showing in the bottom right as 03/10/2013.....So why is it checking it against US format.

tried googling it, got a couple of ans, but nothing concrete,

Anyone know how to change it?
ta

Answer (score 1):

thanks to [How to set Date and time format in IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484053/how-to-set-date-and-time-format-in-iis-7)

I found that I had to change the 'Culture' & 'UI Culture' settings in the IIS from 'invariant' to 'english uk'