# How to resolve Date format change Issue after deployment in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, iis, iis-7

When I'm using DateTime in `dd-MM-yyyy` format.
When I debug my code at localhost its works fine.
But After deploying my ASP.NET web project on IIS server DateTime changes to `mm-dd-yyyy` format automatically.I'm facing many issues because of this problem.
I'm not able to find any solution, please let me know how can I solve this.

How can I get rid of this issue.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484053/how-to-set-date-and-time-format-in-iis-7

Answer (score 3):

1) Change the datetime format of your server from:

Control Panel -> Regional and Language Options -> Advanced

2) Open IIS and follow below steps: (For IIS7)

- Click on you Website
- Select .NET GLOBALIZATION option
- From Culture tab, select required Culture and UI Culture.
- Finally iisreset.

Comment: Thank you! Your `.NET GLOBALIZATION` tip saved me a headache. =)

Answer (score 1):

Your IIS probably has another Localization selected, than on your development machine.

Printing should be pretty simple if you specify the format: `yourDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");`

Parsing a date has been a problem for me in the past. You can change the server settings or specify a CultureInfo directly in the code, like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(myDateString, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```