# Inconsistent DecimalSeparator value

Tags: c#, .net

When I apply `toString()` on a number of type double, I get the string with `.` as the decimal separator. In one of my projects only, I get `,` as the decimal separator.

I have not changed CultureInfo data. My CurrentCulture is `el-GR` in all my projects which is the default system Culture. `el-GR` uses `,` as the decimal separator but I have changed this value through Windows Regional Settings to `.` which is reflected correctly to all my projects except the one in question.

The only difference I can tell is that it is a Web Site and not a usual Visual Studio Project. I do not know if this forces Visual Studio **NOT** to take into account the local computer NumberFormat exceptions and if/how this can be changed.

Comment: I can't tell you why this is happening in this particular case, but you can always pass a specific CultureInfo  as a parameter to `ToString` and most `Parse` methods to ensure you always work with the same culture. You could also check if `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` are identical (e.g. by showing both on a special page).

Comment: I'll randomly guess that the misbehaving project targets an old .NET version.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I would prefer to avoid specifying a CultureInfo as a parameter. I have already made the test you suggest and CurrentCulture is different than CurrentUICulture. But so is in all my other projects. Do you know which of the 2 the framework uses by default?

Comment: @HansPassant It targets version 4.5.2

Comment: en-GB instead of en-GR? GR stands for greece, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @DIe My mistake, it is el-GR.

Comment: the CultureInfo your program use, if you don't explicitly set it somehow in code, is related to Regional Settings of **current user**. When running a web project, very likely current user is not you, the one logged in in the computer, but a built-in user IIS uses. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c) and display somehow current user

Comment: @GianPaolo That is very true indeed! It solves the mystery. How can I mark this comment as the correct answer?

Comment: added my comment as answer @Saloom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CultureInfo your program use, if you don't explicitly set it somehow in code, is related to Regional Settings of **current user**.

When running a web project, very likely current user is not you, the one logged in in the computer, but a built-in user IIS uses. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c) and display somehow current user to find out if your problem is actually related to this.

To change regional settings for your (.Net & IIS hosted) web application, you can use different method: web.config of your application, web.config of the whole server, settings for IIS, or even tweak the registry.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484053/how-to-set-date-and-time-format-in-iis-7) thread (and also linked threads you find in the left column) for methods you can use.