# TextBoxFor helper mixes day and month in dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Please, consider the following example:

1. view model

   ```
   public class FooViewModel
   {
       public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. controller

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       [HttpGet]
       public ActionResult Index(FooViewModel foo)
       {
           return View(foo);
       }
       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Submit(FooViewModel foo)
       {
           return RedirectToAction("Index", foo);
       }
   }
   ```
3. view

   ```
   @model MvcApplication1.Models.FooViewModel
   <h1>@Model.Date</h1>
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
   {
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date)
       <input type="submit" value"Submit" />
   }
   ```
4. routes

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
       null,
       "",
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
   );
   routes.MapRoute(
       null,
       "{action}",
       new { controller = "Home" },
       new { action = "Submit" }
   );
   ```

The problem is that after form submit the date editor gets values with day and month switched:

1. [image: after first submit]
2. [image: after resubmit]

**What can I do to make it work properly?**

---

Actually I tried to format the value of the editor:

1. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { value = Model.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") })`
2. using *editor templates*, as shown in [MVC 2 Editor Template with DateTime](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx), only of course adopted to MVC3; and I also used `EditorFor` helper instead to make the template be utilized.
3. using `DataAnnotations`: `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MMM/dd/yyyy}")]`

None of these changed anything. Neither the value of the editor changed, nor it appeared formatted.

---

In the end I (followed [the answer by **DrJokepu**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961114/date-only-from-textboxfor#answer-1961127)) managed to make this work only with raw HTML, i.e. no helper methods for `DateTime`:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetDateEditor(this FooViewModel model)
{
    string temp = "<input id=\"Date\" type=\"text\" value=\"{0}\" name=\"Date\" 
                    data-val-required=\"Please, enter a valid date\" 
                    data-val=\"true\" />";
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(
                 string.Format(temp, 
                               model == null 
                                    ? string.Empty 
                                    : model.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")));
    }
```

If there is a way to achieve the same result with any of the helper methods remains a secret to me...

Comment: what if you format the date?

Comment: @HanletEscaño I do actually need to format the date in the editor, and this indeed should also solve the problem in question. However, I failed to format it anyway...I'll describe my attempts in the question in a while

Comment: i guess the date format in the database is different that is why its causing the problem you can apply the date format to your ViewModel (if you are using them to bind to the views?)

Comment: @dakait Sorry, what database are you talking about? This example has no database at all.

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov, can't you define the format in your model , something like in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961114/date-only-from-textboxfor

Comment: @Habib I've just checked it. With `TextBoxFor` it still does not apply the format given in the model

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov ah my bad, i thought you are persisting the values in db after form submit...

Comment: @Habib actually, it seems, I tried all the answers given in the question you linked and none of them seem to work. I must be doing something incorrectly....But what??

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov how about setting the date format in the application culture, here is link which shows how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/a/300853/1679410

Comment: @dakait thanks, but actually the culture settings reflect the format I need without any changes. However helper methods do not use it neither as is nor after I used the code in the link you gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try slightly changed version:
`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { @Value = Model.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") })`

Comment: I was absolutely sure I tried this with capital letter `V` and `@` at the beginning and it did not work. I was wrong...