# asp.net mvc format DateTime in whole application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime-format

So basically, what I want is to format `DateTime` in whole application and show it in a specific format in the whole Web App. Is there any better solution to just write `ToString("{0:stringformathere}", obj)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you globally set the date format in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300841/how-do-you-globally-set-the-date-format-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override InitializeCulture method for Web page.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = <some custom culture>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Editor/Display Template and reuse across the application.

***Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CustomDateTime.cshtml***

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    String modelValue = "";
    var dateFormatToDisplay =
       System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;

    if (Model.HasValue)
    {
        if (Model.Value != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            modelValue = Model.Value.ToString(dateFormatToDisplay);
        }
    }
}

@Html.TextBox("", modelValue)
```

In Views

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, "CustomDateTime")
```