# Modification of the language dates on a website

Tags: asp.net, azure, nuget

I am currently developing a website with ASP.NET in which I need to display dates.

The website is hosted in windows azure. When I test my website in local (on my personal computer with the azure emulator), the dates are displayed in French (and this is what I want). But, when I publish and test on azure, the dates are displayed in English. This is a recent problem, it was working some days ago.

I haven't work on the dates themselves, but some packages have been updated (using nuget package manager) on a computer configured in English. I don't know whether it could have an impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the current culture for your thread. It probably defaults to French locally for you, but when it's in Azure, the default is en-US.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300841/how-do-you-globally-set-the-date-format-in-asp-net) for an example on how to set the culture, or override just the date format.

Comment: Ok thanks it works now. 

I already had : 
`CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo) System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
 newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
 newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;`
in my Global.asax file,
but I had to add :
`<system.web>
   <globalization  culture="fr-FR"  uiCulture="fr"/>
</system.web>` in my web.config