# Why are 24 hour DateTime values in database being displayed with am/pm?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a large asp.net MVC web application.

A given message's creation date is stored in the (MS SQL) database as:

```
2015-12-02 18:08:24.383
```

Yet, somehow it is outputted to the web browser as a am/pm date:

```
12/2/2015 6:08:24 PM
```

Why is this? There doesn't seem to be any explicit conversions going on in the controller methods or views. The model value is:

```
public System.DateTime MessageSentDate { get; set; }
```

Then in the View:

`This message was sent on: @message.MessageSentDate`

As you can see, there's no conversion going on here. So why is a 24hr DateTime in the database being output as an am/pm value. Am I just missing something?

I would like to output 24hr format without am or pm. Is there a configuration value that can be assigned to change time display format across the whole app?

Comment: How do you display your `DateTime` exactly as an output? Can you please show your work as well?

Comment: Please show us the code where you are passing the `DateTime` back up to the UI

Comment: Come on guys, can you please wait _at least_ to see the minimal but complete code before you answer it? There can be a lot of reason. I didn't downvote you but we need to see OP's code to give complete answer in my humble opinion.

Comment: `DateTime.ToString()` returns format corresponding to your server side culture. Looks like you have english culture or similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output formats depend on the default settings of your culture. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/300841/342594) for a related question.

Comment: SOLVED. In my Global.asax file: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =  new CultureInfo(Request.UserLanguages[0]);` This essentially means that DateTimes are displayed as per user browser settings.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the output format of your values depends on regional settings.

The regional settings of web applications are defined in `globalization` section of `Web.config`:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-IE" enableClientBasedCulture="false" />
```

Normally, **en-US** culture includes am/pm indicator. To avoid it you can use another culture (f.e. **en-IE**) or you can define the format without am/pm indicator inside your views, like here:

```
This @dt will be shown with default format.

But this @Html.FormatValue(dt, "{0:HH:mm:ss}") will be shown without am/pm.

Also, you can use @(dt.toString("HH:mm:ss")). Parentheses can help to
Razor to parse complex code.
```

**HH** means 24-hour... hours.

When `enableClientBasedCulture` is set to **false**, the format will not depend on user's browser settings (I mean `Accept-Language` HTTP header).

Answer (score 0):

in your controller you can format the date like this:

```
CreatedDate.ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm");
```

this will give you a 24 military time format.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question, and would take a long time to go through each Controller method.

Answer (score -1):

My guess would be that this is due to the culture which sets the Short and Long date formats.  I know that in winforms this can be fairly easily overriden, not sure about MVC though.