# input type date binding in angularjs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using Razor syntax and to bind date type input I used `data_ng_model = 'date'` as it works in html razor. By Default in input field it displays `dd/mm/yyyy`. I am changing value `date` from angularJS script but it doesn't affect the display. Then I used Jquery to change the value attribute of that input field, it changes the value as I observed using inspect element but the display is still `dd/mm/yyyy`. For example if using jquery I change the value to `10/09/2016`, it always displays `dd/mm/yyyy`.
My code is like:

```
date = "10/09/2016";
$scope.date = (date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getDate() + "/" + ((date.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
$("#eventDate").attr("value",$scope.date);
```

I think it should change the display of input field using `$scope.date` as i am binding it like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new {
    @class = "form-control", 
    @type = "date", @id="eventDate", 
    data_ng_model = "date", 
    ng_change = "checkMe()" 
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery dates does not populate model object on post action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183169/jquery-dates-does-not-populate-model-object-on-post-action)

Comment: It needs to add jquery datepicker library, but i am using angularJS, i want to directly bind it