# How to send datetime parameter as DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, datetime, soap

They asked me to create a SOAP webservice with C#. The problem is they want from me to create a function with datetime parameter, and they want to send a formatted string.

Like below,

Decleration: **int func(DateTime)**

Then they want to call it like below,

Function Call: **int result = func("01/01/2017 01:00:00")**

According to my research I didn't find any solution to this.

Is it possible to do declare DateTime and send formatted string to it? Isn't the function decleration must be string, not datetime?

Edit: I was asked this because customer wanted it.

Thanks.

Comment: [`DateTime.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) will format a `DateTime` value into a string. Glad you didn't have any trouble creating the rest of the SOAP web service. Mysterious that you want to create a function that returns an integer when it is given a string that contains a date/time.

Comment: I dont have any trouble on returning values or creating web services. The only problem is in the documentation they wrote to sent the function which i wrote in function call, and for the decleration they want datetime. so i confused. I think it should be declared as string to do that. I didnt get your DateTime.ToString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass a `string` type to a method that accepts `DateTime` .

You can change the method definition to accept a string and then parse the string to get the DateTime value.

Like this :

```
public int YourFunc(string dateString)
{
   DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I was also thinking like that. But in the documentation they wrote datetime. So i confused. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, is there any way to do this in web services? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300841/how-do-you-globally-set-the-date-format-in-asp-net

<system.web>
    <globalization  culture="en-AU"  uiCulture="en-AU"/>
</system.web>