# Convert.ToDateTime to particular format

Tags: c#, datetime

I want the dates in `dd-MM-yyyy` format. I have set it in `Global.asax`. But it gives me following error when I try to convert date string to `DateTime`.

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.
>       Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I don't want to pass the date in string (don't want to use `ToString('format')`). Please help.

Below is my code in `Global.asax`.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo cInfo = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();//new CultureInfo("en-IN");
        cInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
        cInfo.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff";
        cInfo.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cInfo;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cInfo;
    }
```

In `Controller`:-

```
public ActionResult Index(string dateParam)
    {
        DateTime? dataObj = dateParam != null ? DateTime.ParseExact(dateParam, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None) : (DateTime?)null;
       // -- Do something --
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Possibly duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300841/how-do-you-globally-set-the-date-format-in-asp-net

Comment: Where is the code where you do the actual conversion?

Comment: @Sefe - Please see the edit.

Comment: This maybe help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture(v=VS.110).aspx

Comment: `DateTime dateObj` this is a DateTime object which has no format

Comment: Are you using a `DateTimePicker` or a standard `TextBox` as an input control?

Comment: Your code that sets the culture is in which event handler in Global.asax?  If you want it to apply to all requests, you might want to put it in, say, Application_BeginRequest.

Comment: @Joe - It's in `Begin_Request`

Comment: @DhavalR an MCVE would help.

Comment: @Joe not everyone is familar with that abbreviation (MCVE = https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Joe - I have updated my question. Please see the code in `Global.asax` and `Controller`.

Comment: Why are you passing in the `InvariantCulture`?  That's not going to use your culture settings.

Comment: What is the contents of `dateParam` ? I bet it is not in the format `dd-MM-yyyy`, is it?

Comment: @RandRandom - most people have access to google though.

Comment: @Joe if those people would know how to use google they wouldnt ask questions :)

Comment: @Fildor - It is in `dd-MM-yyyy` format.

Comment: @RandRandom - fair point.  Maybe the comment editor should automatically change MCVE to a link to that help page, to help people as lazy as me.